# Color each facet by different variable value

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(100, 0, 1),
                y = runif(100, 1, 2),
                var1 = runif(100, 0, 1),
                var2 = runif(100, 0, 1),
                var3 = rep(c("a", "b"), 50))
```

I want to make a faceted plot in ggplot2 that plots the same `x` vs `y` in each facet (scatterplot), but colors by the values of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`. In this case, there would only be 3 facets, one for each of the coloring columns.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plots = lapply(3:5, function(i){
    dt = df[,c(1, 2, i)]
    ggplot(data = dt, aes_string(x = names(dt)[1],
                                 y = names(dt)[2],
                                 color = names(dt[3]))) +
        geom_point()
})
library(gridExtra)
do.call(function(...){
    grid.arrange (..., ncol = 3)},
    plots)
```

[image: Rplot]